# When can i see my Feature Graphic in android market?

Tags: android

I uploaded promotional and feature graphic images with my application apk to android market.

No ware feature graphic image is visible in my application page of android market

When and where can i see the feature graphic image in my application market page?

is displaying of feature graphic depends on ratings of the app or any other things?

Comment: Did your feature graphic ever show? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

You can see it here: https://market.android.com/
The smaller promotional image should show in the description of your app on both web and phone android market.